# getPass() echoing password in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

Hey all just started dabbling in a little Python to help out with a few scripts at work, but I seem to be getting hung up on a little issue.

I am using Eclipse with pydev for my development platform and developing against python 2.7.3. I am just trying to prompt a user for their password, using:

```
password = getpass.getpass()
```

That line works as expected when running in the terminal/command prompt, however when I am running in the Eclipse console, the user's input isn't hidden like it should be. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented behaviour - some terminals are not capable of echo-free input, in that case, it should give a warning instead:

> If echo free input is unavailable getpass() falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from sys.stdin and issuing a GetPassWarning.

[From the docs for `getpass.getpass()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass).

Comment: I see no warning printing to the console though.

Comment: @BrentHronik That is interesting. I can't tell you why that would be the case.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Do you know of any workarounds for the case when getpass() is unable to hide the input?

Comment: @BrentHronik If a terminal can't do it, it can't do it. Not much one can do about that (besides give a warning, which it is meant to do). My guess is that eclipse is lying and saying it will hide the input, but doesn't as it could be easier for debugging stuff.