# Hide console input with Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, console-input

I am quite new to Python and started using Eclipse with Pydev recently. I am writing a script where I'd like to enter a password via the console, and the password should not be displayed.

So far I was calling `getpass.getpass()`, which was fine when I ran my script in command line, but run in Eclipse the password is displayed while typing it. Apparently, this is a documented behavior for `getpass`. Do you know any workaround for this ?

Comment: short answer: you can't


long answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668607/getpass-echoing-password-in-eclipse